# Determining $u=v \times w$ using the cross product

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, cross-product

Let $v = (3,0,0)$ and $w=(0,1,-1).$ Determine $u = v \times w$ using the geometric properties of the cross product rather than the formula.

What are the possible angles $x$ between two unit vectors $e$ and $f$ if $||e \times f||=1/2$?

For the first question, the way I approached it was by using the cross product before I used the geometric properties of the cross product. So, after doing little bit of algebra for $u = v \times w,$ I computed $= 0i+3j+3k=(0,3,3)$ but something looks wrong. For the second question, I suspect that the answer is $\frac{pi}{2}$ but don't know how to show it. Much appreciated.

Comment: "I approached it by using the cross product before I used its geometric properties" - so you used a formula to compute it? Do you know what geometric properties of $\times$ to use to figure out the cross product without plugging anything into a formula? For the second question, are you familiar with the formula $\|e\times f\|=\|e\|\|f\|\sin\theta$?

Comment: I am a bit confused with the geometric properties of the cross product. So I figured if I used the cross product first, I might get deeper intuition which is why after an attempt I came for help. As for your second remark, yes I am, little bit anyways. But since I don't know the unit vector of e and f, I don't know how to use that formula.

Comment: If $\|e\|=\|f\|=1$ and $\|e\times f\|=1/2$ then what does the formula say?

Comment: If the magnitude of e and f are equal to 1, then the cross product of e and f are equal to the vector length of the two vectors times the sine of theta, or the angle between them, which is 1/2. So if e and f are equal to one, then that would mean the angle is 30 degrees or pi/6. Is his correct?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning) on the geometric interpretation of the cross product for part one. For part two, you will realize your answer is incorrect by using the same geometric interpretation: if two unit vectors have angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then the magnitude of their cross product must equal one. You can also directly compute the result using $||a\times b|| = ||a||||b||\,sin{\theta}$